# Use of typedef in c programming language?

Tags: c

I have learned about typedef  uses but I can't understand this following code,

```
typedef enum{FALSE, TRUE} Boolean;
```

What is the meaning of this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that `FALSE` is an `int` type with value 0 and `TRUE` is an `int` type with value 1

Then `Boolean` can be used as a type; you've introduced it into the `typedef` namespace. But note that other `int` values other than 0 and 1 can be set to it. So it's not a true *Boolean* type in the sense of the one in C++ or Java.

These days though don't do that. Use `<stdbool.h>` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation :)